# CodeIgniter | Customized info_windows of google map API

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I am using a CodeIgniter google map library from biostall.com
http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library

Every things works very fine. However, I would like to customize the style of info window. I am reading this: http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries

However, I have no idea how to do. Anyone can get me a help?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning. Thanks for using my library. What you're after means incorporating an additional library that doesn't form part of the base Google Maps API.

Remember, all the CodeIgniter library does is aid in outputting the JavasScript required to generate maps. As a result there's no reason to say you can't basterdize it to do what you require.

I have done similar things recently, particularly with the 'MarkerWithLabel' library, so if you need a hand or any advice please contact me through my site and I'll be happy to help out where I can.

Thanks and speak soon,

Steve